# Is it possible to access a HTML element by its descent hidden value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list like below.

```
 <ul class="groupList" id="groupList">  
 <li id="group1">
      <div class="1">
      ......
      </div>
      <div class="2">
      <select class.....>
      <input type="hidden" value="blah" id="groupField1" name="groupField1"/>
      </div>
 </li>
 <li>....</li>
 <li>....</li>
 </ul>
```

How can i get the "li" element which has hidden text of value blah.There can be several "li" element which have a hidden text of value "blah".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a version that will work on older browsers too...

```
var matchedLi = [],
    li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0, liLength = li.length; i < liLength; i++) {
    var input = li[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var j = 0, inputLength = input.length; j < inputLength; j++) {
        if (input[j].type == 'hidden' && input[j].value == 'blah') {
            matchedLi.push(li[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HKhSd/).

If using jQuery...

```
var matchedLi = $('li:has(:hidden[value="blah"])');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQfKr/).

Answer (score 2):

Use xpath

```
 var findPattern = "//li[input[@type='hidden' and @value='blah']]";

 var resultLinks = document.evaluate( findPattern, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );


 for ( var i=0; (res = resultLinks.snapshotItem(i) ) !=null; i ++ ){

 }
```

EDIT: forgotten blah value

Answer (score 1):

using jquery

```
$(function(){    
     alert($('input[value="blah"]').length);  
});
```

using classic javascript :

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var i = elems.length;
var arr = [];

while(i--){
    if (elems[i].value == 'blah'){
        arr.push(elems[i]);
    }   
}
alert(arr.length);
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ShlomiKomemi/dvdPd/13/

Comment: Attribute filters are required to be quoted - i.e. `input[value="blah"]`

Comment: @Thief I think they work without being quoted too, depending on the string being matched.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it works or not: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ - "An attribute value. **Quotes are mandatory.**"

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it can be done in simple javascript :
http://jsfiddle.net/ZCTvp/

```
var parentCont = document.getElementById('groupList');

var children = parentCont.getElementsByTagName('li');

var check = 'blah';
/* now loop the LIs and find relevant INPUT */

for(var i = 0 ; i < children.length ; i++)
{
    var currChild = children[i];
    var inputs = currChild.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for(var j = 0 ; j < inputs.length ; i++)
    {
       if(inputs[i].value == check)
             alert(inputs[i].id);
    }  


}
```

Comment: The jQuery solution is much nicer - but +1 for giving an example why plain Javascript is inferior regarding readability.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's an HTML5 tag on the question, perhaps the solution is only required to work in in browsers that support suitable HTML5 features. If so, you can use *querySelectorAll* with a simple *upTo* function:

```
// Use qSA to get the input
function getLis() {
  if (!document || !document.querySelectorAll) return;
  var lis = []
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[value='blah']");

  for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    lis.push(upTo(inputs[i], 'li'));
  }
  return lis;
}


// Supporting 'upTo' function to go up the DOM from an element
// to the first with tagName
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  while (el) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
}
```

You might want to pass the value used in the selector to the function rather than having it hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you can do `$("input[value='blah']")` to get the set of input elements with a `value` of "blah".

To then get the parent `li` of the input field you can use `closest("li")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery, you can use this code:

```
$("#id_of_blah").closest("li")
```

If you don't, you have to write your own function which selects the closest `<li>` to your hidden value.